# How to Search in file with sub-string contain backslash and \n

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

How do I search in a file for a sub-string containing a backslash?

```
substring="test\\123\\n"
filename="temp.txt"
file = open(filename, "r")
for line in file:
    if re.search(substring, line):
```

temp.txt

```
sometexttest\123\ntest
secoundline
...
etc
```

How to search string contain backslash and `\n` like `"test\\123\\n"`.
I tried  adding one more backslash but it is not working.

Comment: try with `substring = r'test\123\n'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what your looking for?

```
substring="test\\1234\\n"
filename="temp.txt"
file = open(filename, "r")

for line in file:
    if substring in line:
        print line
```

Giving the output:

```
sometexttest\1234\ntest
```

Answer (score 1):

The `re.search()` call compiles your pattern and *also* interprets the backslashed expressions. Use `re.escape()` to prevent that:

```
if re.search(re.escape(substring), line):
```

Better still, don't use `re.search()` at all, you are looking for literal text here so a simple membership test should do:

```
if substring in line:
```